# What exactly do the LC_* locale strings on Linux mean?

Tags: linux, locale, charset

When I type on my Linux command prompt

```
locale
```

I get a long list of `LC_*` variables (like `LC_TIME` and so on). The value of the variables looks something like the ones from this list:

```
en_US.8859-1
de_DE@euro
fr_FR.utf-8
```

What exactly do the individual parts mean?

I know that `@euro` is identical to `.8859-15` and generally the last part means the actual charset (the mapping of bytes to actual symbols). But what exactly do the first two codes "do"? What properties of the system do they influence? For example (just to have some example to work with), what is the difference between `en_US.8859-15`, `de_DE.8859-15`, `de_CH.8859-15` and `en_CU.8859-15`? All have the exact same charset, so all textfiles that I open in the editor of my choice would looke the same. So what would happen if I switch from one "pre-charset code" to another "pre-charset code" (like from `de_CH` to `en_US`)?

Are there any tables that list the differences in a nice, easy-to-read table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts form an [ISO-639 language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639).  The first part is the language itself, and the second is (usually) a [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) specifying which local variant.

You can observe the effect of changing `LANG` with almost any program that has translations.  `LC_COLLATE` affects the results of the `sort` program; `LC_DATE` affects the output of `date` and `ls -l`.  For some locale settings, it's possible (even likely) that you have nothing installed that uses them.

On most systems, only `LC_LANG` is set, and all the other settings fall back to inheriting from that.

The following quote from the man page of `locale`(7) is relevant:

> **LC_COLLATE**
>   This is used to change the behavior of the functions strcoll(3) and strxfrm(3), which are used to compare strings in the local alphabet.  For example, the German sharp s is sorted as "ss".
>   **LC_CTYPE**
>                 This changes the behavior of the character handling and classification functions, such as isupper(3) and toupper(3), and the multibyte character functions such as mblen(3) or wctomb(3).
>   **LC_MONETARY**
>                 changes  the  information returned by localeconv(3) which describes the way numbers are usually printed, with details such as decimal point versus decimal comma.  This information is internally used by the function
>                 strfmon(3).
>   **LC_MESSAGES**
>                 changes the language messages are displayed in and what an affirmative or negative answer looks like.  The GNU C-library contains the gettext(3), ngettext(3), and rpmatch(3) functions  to  ease  the  use  of  these
>                 information.  The GNU gettext family of functions also obey the environment variable LANGUAGE (containing a colon-separated list of locales) if the category is set to a valid locale other than "C".
>   **LC_NUMERIC**
>                 changes the information used by the printf(3) and scanf(3) family of functions, when they are advised to use the locale-settings.  This information can also be read with the localeconv(3) function.
>   **LC_TIME**
>                 changes the behavior of the strftime(3) function to display the current time in a locally acceptable form; for example, most of Europe uses a 24-hour clock versus the 12-hour clock used in the United States.
>   **LC_ALL** All of the above.